# what does SychronizedInputPattern do in UI-Automation?

Tags: c#, ui-automation

Could some one explain what the SychronizedInputPattern does? I haven't been able to find any good examples of it being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets suppose you need to click something but before the click happens, the elements move (maybe due to resize …). In this case, some other element could get the mouse input.

To overcome this problem, SynchronizedInputPattern has been introduced.

```
buttonElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailableProperty);
```

Read more over [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/11/18/new-wpf-features-synchronizedinputpattern.aspx).. Example can be [downloaded here](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-09-92-23-40/UIA.zip).